# cross_validate with custom score function

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I try to use my own function while cross_validating but I have the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:774: UserWarning: Scoring failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. Details: 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3361, in get_loc
        return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
      File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 76, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
      File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
      File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 2131, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
      File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 2140, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
    KeyError: 1418
```

Here is my custom function:

```
def net_margin(y_true, y_pred):

    net_marg = 0
    n = len(y_pred)

    for i in range(0,n) :

      if y_pred[i] == 1 :
        if y_true[i] == 1 : 
          net_marg += 7.5

      elif y_pred[i] == -1 :
        if y_true[i] == -1 : 
          net_marg += 4.5

      else :

        net_marg += -0.5

    return net_marg
```

and here is my code for the cross validation:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, accuracy_score, cohen_kappa_score

accuracy = make_scorer(accuracy_score)
kappa = make_scorer(cohen_kappa_score)
net_marg = make_scorer(net_margin)

results = cross_validate(dt, x_train, y_train, cv=10, scoring=net_marg)

print(results)
```

When I use my `net_margin` function without `cross_validate` it works well.

Here is a link to a sample of train data :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vXCvEIG97eTVYHgfsQJ9ENXU0t33M127CcaV4Jm3tbM/edit?usp=sharing

And here is how I define `x_train` and `y_train`:

```
train2 = pd.DataFrame.copy(train)

x_train = train2.drop(columns= ["ID_CLIENT", "C1_A_Chanson Francaise_La Nouvelle scene", "C2_A_Polars / SF_Polars", "C3_A_Pop-Rock_Rock independant", "C4_A_Films_Action et Policier", "C5_A_Films_Cinephiles", "C6_A_BD_BD Mangas", "C7_A_Maison / Loisirs_Tourisme", "C8_A_Romans_Bests sellers", "C9_A_Pop-Rock_Pop-Rock FM", "C10_A_Films_Drames"])

y_train = train2["C3_A_Pop-Rock_Rock independant"]

for i in range(0, len(train["C3_A_Pop-Rock_Rock independant"])) :

  if train["C3_A_Pop-Rock_Rock independant"][i] == 1 : 
        y_train[i] = 1

  elif train["C6_A_BD_BD Mangas"][i] == 1 :
    y_train[i] = -1

  else :
    y_train[i] = 0
```

Comment: Could you please add information on the dataset used, the problem e. g. multiclass classifcation and  on your model e. g. Decision Tree? I can not reproduce the error for a random data set with a decision tree as a classifcator.

Comment: this is a classification problem, there is two binary columns to predict but I have combined both into one array which is equal to : 1 if the first column is true or both are true, -1 if the 2nd column is true, and 0 if neither is true. So the y_train is an array of -1, 1 and 0's. The variables of the x_train are numerical ones. And I use a Decision tree : ```dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=10, min_samples_leaf=248, criterion='gini', class_weight='balanced')```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please also edit in a sample of the features and targets, so that I can recreate?

Comment: I've edited my original post, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You get the `KeyError`, as you access the `pd.Series` with a key, that is not part of the index of `y_train`.

Here is the problematic part:

```
y_true:20    0
...
28    0
Name: C3_A_Pop-Rock_Rock independant, dtype: int64
```

Your series index ranges of `y_train` in one of the fold ranges from 20 to 28. You loop however from 0 to 8 and try to access the series at location 0, which is not part of the index.

To fix it,  hand over a `np.array` to `cross_validate(...)` through `y_train.values`.

```
dt = DecisionTreeClassifier()
net_marg = make_scorer(net_margin)

results = cross_validate(dt, x_train, y_train.values, cv=3, scoring=net_marg)

print(results)
```

**Hint:** You could replace the loop in `net_margin()` with some matrix calculus.